# php login page worked in localhost but not in live server

Tags: php

I have been tired of finding out why this login.php can run well in localhost enviroment but not in the live server. when login, error with wrong username & password but while in localhost, successful. connection with db is correct.

anyone can help me check my coding.

below is my code

```
<?php require_once('Connections/conn.php'); ?>
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_POST["s_username"]) && isset($_POST["s_password"])){

    $s_username = $_POST["s_username"];
    $s_password = $_POST["s_password"];

echo "<script>window.alert('$s_username - $s_password');</script>";

    $sql= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM student WHERE studentNo = $s_username AND studentPswd = $s_password LIMIT 1");
    $sql2= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM clockin WHERE studentNo = '$s_username' AND status=0 LIMIT 1");

    $existCount = mysql_num_rows($sql);

    $s_status = "1";
    if($existCount==1){
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
            $s_no=$row['studentNo'];
            $s_name=$row['studentName'];

        }
        if($existCount2==1){
        while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($sql2)){
                    $s_status=$row2['status'];
                    $s_clockid=$row2['clockID'];
                }}

        $_SESSION["s_no"]=$s_no;
        $_SESSION["MM_Username"]=$s_username;

        if($sql==true){

            echo "<script>window.alert('Login Success');</script>";
</script>";

                        if($s_status==1){

                            header("refresh:1 ,url=beginSession.php ");
                            exit();
                        }

                        else {

                        echo "<script>window.alert('Sesi Lepas Belum Ditamatkan.');</script>";
            header("refresh:1 ,url=startedSession2.php?clockid=$s_clockid");
                        exit(); 

                        }
                }
    }
    else{
         echo "<script>window.alert('Login Failed.');</script>";
         header("refresh:1 ,url=login.php");
         exit();
    }  
}

?>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper-page">
            <div class="panel panel-color panel-primary panel-pages">
                <div class="panel-heading bg-img"> 
                    <div class="bg-overlay"></div>

                    <h3 class="text-center m-t-10 text-white"><strong>Masuk ke</strong> 
                    <p><a href="#"><img src="img/logo2.png" alt="" title=""></a></p></h3>
                </div> 


                <div class="panel-body">
                <form class="form-horizontal m-t-20" id="form1" method="post" action="login.php">

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <input name="s_username" class="form-control input-lg" type="text" required="" placeholder="Username">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <input name="s_password" class="form-control input-lg" type="password" required="" placeholder="Password">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group text-center m-t-40">
                        <div class="col-xs-12"><label>
                                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg w-lg waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" value="Log in">Log In</button></label>
                                <label><a href="reg2.php" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg w-lg waves-effect waves-light">Daftar Baru</a></label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form> 
                </div>                                 
            </div>
        </div>
</body>
```

I hope anyone can help me.

Thank you

Comment: There's a syntax error, see the highlighted code. What version is your PHP on the server?

Comment: wait, did you just save plain password on database?

Comment: error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);   check any error?

Comment: php version 5.5

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
session_start();
require_once('Connections/conn.php');
```

`session_start();` is always top of the page.

also remove the additional closing :

```
echo "<script>window.alert('Login Success');</script>";
```

Answer (score 1):

This code is causing syntax error:

```
    echo "<script>window.alert('Login Success');</script>";
</script>";
```

Remove the additional `</script>"`:

```
 echo "<script>window.alert('Login Success');</script>";
```

https://www.tinywebhut.com/errors-and-custom-error-handling-in-php-56

**Be Careful**

You are using deprecated `mysql`, use `mysqli` extension instead. I suppose you are aware of SQL injection. Always use prepared statements.

Prepared statements already help to remove a ton of problems to get the query working.